# Button Count with minimum limit

Tags: xamarin.forms

Please I need assistance on how to create a button, to count the certain numbers, for example: 1-3 or 1-12 only.

Thanks.

This is the example of my page:

CountPage.xaml

```
<StackLayout Spacing="8">
                                    <Label Text="0" x:Name="labelCount" 
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                                    <Button Text="Count" Clicked="Increment"/>
                                </StackLayout>
```

CountPage.xaml.cs

```
int labelValue = 0;
        public CountPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Increment(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            labelValue++;
            labelCount.Text = labelValue.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost the same as before.

But you will have to modify your starting value to be 1 instead of 0.

And you will need a max value

```
Int labelValue = 1;
Int maxValue = 12;

public CountPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Increment(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(labelValue >= maxValue)
  {
   //Reset the value and start again
   labelValue = 0;
   }
 labelValue++;
 labelCount.Text = labelValue.ToString();
 }
```

When the label count variable reaches the desired value, you start counting again from the start.

But if you want, you can disable the button after the desired number has been reached.